# Validating Currency on Javascript using a regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for currency type. 
Requirements :

```
1. First char can be a '$'. It can appear either 0 or 1 times.
2. Then a digit can appear multiple times.
3. Then a decimal point can appear either 0 or 1 time.
4. After this, a digit can appear 0 or more times.
```

I have written the following regular expression :

```
\$?\d+\.?\d*
```

I need to test this on JS . This is how i test this on JS;

```
var str = "$cng";
var patt = new RegExp('[\$?\d+\.?\d*]');
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

The above string $cng is returning true. I am not able to get it. Am i missing anything here. Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var patt = new RegExp("\\$?\\d+\\.?\\d*");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must need to escape all the backslashes one more times when passing it to the RegExp constructor which has double quotes as delimiter.
2. And also i suggest you to remove the square brackets around your pattern.

So change your pattern like below,

```
var patt = new RegExp("^\\$?\\d+\\.?\\d*$");
```

OR

```
var patt = new RegExp("^\\$?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$");
```

Example:

```
> var str = "$123.12";
undefined
> var patt = new RegExp("^\\$?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$");
undefined
> patt.test(str);
true
> var patt = new RegExp("^\\$?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$");
undefined
> patt.test('$123.12$');
false
```

Comment: var str = "$123.12$";  The above expression returns true for this string too. This is not desired

Answer (score 0):

```
[\$?\d+\.?\d*]==>[] is a character class.
```

Your regex will just match `1 character` out of the all defined inside the character class.

Use

```
^\\$?\\d+\\.?\\d*$
```

or

```
/^\$?\d+\.?\d*$/
```

to be very safe.

Comment: Or even better, `/^\$?\d+\.?\d*$/` to avoid an escape orgy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `RegExp('[\$?\d+\.?\d*]')` with `RegExp(/\$?\d+\.?\d*/)` and it will work as expected.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var str = "$100.10";
var patt = new RegExp(/^\$?\d+\.?\d*$/);
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

**EDIT:**

You can also simply do: `var res = /^\$?\d+\.?\d*$/.test(str);`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should also match the beginning and end of the string, otherwise it will only test if the string *contains* a currency:

```
^\$?\d+\.?\d*$
```

You added brackets around the regular expression when you implemented it in Javascript, which changes the meaning entirely. The pattern will find a match if any of the characters within the brackets exist in the string, and as there is a `$` in the string the result was `true`.

Also, when you have a regular expression in a string, you have to escape the backslashes:

```
var patt = new RegExp('^\\$?\\d+\\.?\\d*$');
```

You can also use a regular expression literal to create the object:

```
var patt = /^\$?\d+\.?\d*$/;
```

---

You might want to change the requirements so that the decimal point only is allowed if there are digits after it, so that for example `$1.` is not a valid value:

```
^\$?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```